# NAT in AT&T Uverse: multiple web servers for different domains

Tags: port-forwarding, http, nat

I'm hosting a couple different websites on a couple different computers on my home network. I'm trying to configure my firewall settings such that it allows HTTP traffic to both of those computers and distinguishes between them by domain name. Is this possible to do? How can I have two different HTTP servers on the same local network visible to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one public IP address, you can't host multiple http sites on multiple servers using the same port (80).

To make this work you would need to use unique ports for each server, such as 80, 81, and 82. Which also requires using a unique URL for each:

http://webserver1.com
http://webserver2.org:81
http://webserver3.net:82

In this case, just port forward a unique port to each server and substite that port in the URL entered in the browser.

However, if all website were hosted on the same server like IIS or Apache as virtual sites this would possible, it's part of http/1.1 specifications and uses the HOST parameter to request what sitename it's looking for.

If these are HTTPS sites, forget it. Each site must have its own unique public IP address. The ssl key exchange and certificate verification take place prior to the http transaction, so the http server won't know to give out the certificate for webserver1.com or webserver2.net